# Python: split dataframe into multiple dataframes by using for loop with locals function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, local-variables

I have a csv file below:

```
name,apply,percent
A,101,98%
B,388,79%
C,637,88%
D,541,75%
E,345,98%
A,446,85%
D,211,49%
```

I tried to split dataframe into multiple dataframes as df_A, df_B, df_C, df_D & df_E.

```py
for name in df.groupby('name'):
    locals()['df_'.name]=df[(df.name==name)]
     print(df_A)
```

It doesn't work. How to fix the code? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
>>> for name in df['name'].unique():
...     locals()['df_' + name] = df[(df.name == name)]
...
>>> df_A
  name  apply percent
0    A    101     98%
5    A    446     85%
>>> df_B
  name  apply percent
1    B    388     79%
>>> df_C
  name  apply percent
2    C    637     88%
>>> df_D
  name  apply percent
3    D    541     75%
6    D    211     49%
>>> df_E
  name  apply percent
4    E    345     98%
```

Comment: Suppose there was another column in the df called 'city' and we wanted to split the larger df into smaller dfs by name and city.  How would you modify the for loop to account for this?